# How to get Pomodoro Clock to work on CodePen?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The following code for a React Pomodoro Clock has been input into CodePen exactly into the CodePen JS editor and HTML editor, and then `save` clicked. However, CodePen does not display the Pomodoro Clock, and where the clock should appear there is only a blank orange page. There is no indication why on CodePen. Actual link: `https://codepen.io/controlunit/pen/dyMrMxy` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

/*
* A simple React component
*/
const initState = {
  breakLength: 5,
  sessionLength: 25,
  init: 'session',
  stateIndex: 0,
  timeLeft: undefined,
  timeLeftSeconds: undefined,
  started: false,
  intervalFunc: undefined
}

const states = [ { name: 'session', duration: 1500 }, { name: 'break', duration: 300 } ]

const secondsToMins = (time) => {
  let converted = ('0' + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);
  return converted;
}

class Clock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initState;
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sessionSeconds = this.state.sessionLength * 60;
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(sessionSeconds) });
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    // decrements the breakLength and the breakSeconds
    // breakLength is only a number ie. 5 (does not show seconds)
    // breakSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength - 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength + 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    // decrements the sessionLength and the sessionSeconds
    // sessionLength is only a number ie. 25 (does not show seconds)
    // sessionSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength - 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength-1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength-1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength-1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength + 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength+1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength+1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength+1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  startStop(id) {
    // starts the countDown, which runs continuously until the start/stop button
    // is pressed again, which pauses the countdown.
    // the id parameter is used by countDown to play the audio beep
    if(!this.state.started){
      this.countDown(id);
      this.setState({ started: true});
    }
    // pauses the countDown
    if(this.state.started){
      let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
      clearInterval(intervalFunc);
      this.setState({ started: false});
    }
  }

  reset() {
    let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    // reset state to default values
    this.setState({ breakLength: 5 });
    this.setState({ sessionLength: 25 });
    this.setState({ init: 'session' });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: 1500})
    this.setState({ timeLeft: '25:00' });
    this.setState({ stateIndex: 0 });
    this.setState({ started: false });
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: undefined });
  }

  countDown(id){
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(() => down(this.state.timeLeftSeconds--), 1000);
    this.setState({intervalFunc: intervalFunc});

    const down = (time) =>
    {

      if(time > 0){
        // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
      }

      if (time <= 0) {

        let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
        sound.play();

        let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
        this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex});
        this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: states[stateIndex].duration});
        this.setState({ init: states[stateIndex].name});
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});

        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
        console.log(this.state.init);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="clock">
      <h1 id="title">25-5 Clock</h1>

      <div>
      <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
      <p id="break-length">{this.state.breakLength}</p>
      <button id="break-decrement" onClick={e => this.breakDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="break-increment" onClick={e => this.breakIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <div>
      <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
      <p id="session-length">{this.state.sessionLength}</p>
      <button id="session-decrement" onClick={e => this.sessionDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="session-increment" onClick={e => this.sessionIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <hr/>

      <div>
      <p id="timer-label">{this.state.init}</p>
      <p id="time-left">{this.state.timeLeft}</p>
      <button id="start_stop" onClick={e => this.startStop(e.target.id)}><audio id="beep" src='./beep.mp3'></audio> start/stop </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick={e => this.reset()}> reset </button>
      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};

/*
* Render the above component into the div#app
*/
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>25-5 Clock</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="app"></app>
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Apart from missing Babel, I think you need to add some libs, e.g. react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using JSX in your javascript without transpiling it. Go into codepen's settings and under the javascript tab select 'babel' as the javascript preprocessor.

Comment: Ok, set to babel, but the page is still blank.

Comment: Different error. Open the browser's devtools and look at the error in the console.

Comment: CodePen is giving an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Yep. `require` isn't supported in the browser.

Comment: In CodePen settings, babel, and the react and react-dom libraries were added, yet after adding these the page remains blank. However, the entire folder of the project code was successfully uploaded to GitHub, and then imported into CodeSandBox.io, and is working in CodeSandBox,io

Comment: This is why I didn't want to do the session in codepen yesterday.

Comment: Right. Weirdly CodeSandbox.io would not load, and I had to fully wipe out caches to get it to finally work. Thanks!